# Selenium error on ubuntu: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome

When I am trying to run webdriver (chrome) I gets error "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally". I have this error only on linux, on my PC (windows) I don't have this error.

google-chrome version: **73.0.3683.86**

chromedriver version: **ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68**

Ubuntu version: **18.04**

I  have tried running Xvfb, and exporting screen.

```
Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Chrome options:

```
    var chromeDesktop = {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [/*`--proxy-server=${proxyUrl}`,*/'user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"','--disable-web-security','--allow-running-insecure-content'],
                    "prefs": {
                        "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2
                    },
                    "extensions": [
                         encode('./anti-captcha.crx')
                    ]
                }
            };
```

I can not run code in headless, beacuse I must load extension. What can I do?

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure why the old post was deleted (being marked it as duplicate).

Please see these two links -

- https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/2362#issuecomment-402442392
- [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d)

In your chromeOptions, add `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage` options along with the other args that you have put - like this

```
"args": [/*`--proxy-server=${proxyUrl}`,*/'user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"','--disable-web-security','--allow-running-insecure-content','--no-sandbox','--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
```

Comment: I have tried adding these arguments, but it still does not work. I also tried lowering chromedriver version (which supports v73 chrome), but it does not work too.

Comment: Are you running headless chrome?

Comment: No, I can not run headless chrome, beacuse headless chrome doesn't support extesnions.